# Java is printing two seperate sout statements on the same line for no reason?

Tags: java, netbeans

For some reason java has been acting weird today and is displaying two print statements on the same line despite the code being sound.

```
        flag2 = false; // error trapping
        System.out.print("\n What would you like to do? ");
        System.out.println(" 1) View Calender");
        System.out.println(" 2) Add a task");
        System.out.println(" 3) Delete a task");
        System.out.println(" 4) Save&Quit Program");
        String choice = scanN.next();
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: *"For some reason java has been acting weird today ... "* - What has happened >today< is that you have written some code with a bug in it.  This code would have printed the same result in Java 1.0 ... in 1995.  Advice: 1) read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) to understand the difference between `print` and `println`, 2) every day remind yourself that 99.9% of bugs are actually in >your< code, not in Java itself.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.print` will NOT print a newline at the end (unless you explicitly specify it to)! `System.out.println` will.

So either go `System.out.print("\n What would you like to do? \n");`

or use `System.out.println("\n What would you like to do? ");`

Answer (score 1):

You used System.out.print instead of System.out.println and  that is the cause of 2 statements being in the same line. Just change the first print statement to System.out.println and youre god to go.